# Couldn't match type `float' with `Int'

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function calculating standard deviation.

**Code:**

```
stdDev :: [float]->float
stdDev []  = 0.0
stdDev list = sqrt (foldl (\x->  fromIntegral(x^2/length list)) 0 list - foldl (\x->fromIntegral(x/length list)^2) 0 list)
```

When compile, it shows:

```
Couldn't match type `float' with `Int'
```

I already cast it by using fromIntegral. I don't understand why it is still complaining about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, types have to start with an upper case letter.  If they don't they're interpreted as type variables

```
stdDev :: [Float] -> Float
stdDev [] = 0.0
```

Next, you don't need all those `fromIntegral`s in there, you aren't working with `Integral` types.  If we use a where clause for calculating the length, we also get a more efficient function.  Unfortunately you're not quite using `foldl` correctly, it takes a function of two arguments and you're only passing it a function of 1.  You also have your standard deviation function a bit off, it should look like

```
stdDev xs = sqrt $ (sum $ map (^2) xs) / l - (sum xs / l) ^ 2
    where l = fromIntegral $ length xs
```

As a final improvement, you can make this work for any type that implements `Floating`, which includes `Float` and `Double` by using a type class

```
stdDev :: Floating a => [a] -> a
stdDev [] = 0
stdDev xs = sqrt $ (sum $ map (^2) xs) / l - (sum xs / l) ^ 2
    where l = fromIntegral $ length xs
```

And so we can test it out:

```
> stdDev [1, 1, 1]
0.0
> stdDev [2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9]
2.0
```

So it looks like it's working

---

If you're really wanting to use a fold, you have to pass it a function that takes two arguments.  The general pattern to use is

```
foldl (\acc x -> <expr>) <initial value> <list>
```

For a sum, it's as simple as

```
foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs
```

But for performance reasons you should actually use `foldr` here, and it can be reduced to simply

```
foldr (+) 0 xs
```

In your case, you need a simple sum and then a sum of squares, so you can do

```
mySum xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
sumSqrs xs = foldr (\acc x -> acc + x ^ 2) 0 xs
```

So you can use these in `stdDev` as

```
stdDev xs = sqrt $ foldr (\acc x -> acc + x ^ 2) 0 xs / l - (foldr (+) 0 xs / l) ^ 2
    where l = fromIntegral $ length xs
```

Comment: As I told @David.. I am forcing my self to use foldl.. I think I got two paras, first is the function and second one is 0, whcih is the cumulative value?

Comment: The function that you're passing to `foldl` must take two arguments, but right now both of them just take one: `x`.

Comment: Could you explain how "\acc x -> acc + x ^ 2" works? What is acc's initial value?

Comment: @NobWong The initial value of `acc` is the second argument to the fold, in this case `0`.  What the fold does is take the initial value and the first element of the list, apply the function to them, and then uses the output with the second element of the list, and uses that result with the third, and so on.  If you ran `foldr (+) 0 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, it would compute (roughly) `0 + 1 = 1 => 1 + 2 = 3 => 3 + 3 = 6 => 6 + 4 = 10 => 10 + 5 = 15`.

Comment: why x doesn't need "\"?

Comment: @NobWong That's the syntax for making [lambda functions](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Anonymous_function).  You only need one `\` when declaring a lambda, and aside from using `->` instead of `=`, it has the same syntax as a normal function, so multiple arguments are separated by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`float` should be capitalized: `Float`. Anything in a type signature that starts with a lowercase letter is a type variable in Haskell.

Additionally, the function passed to `foldl` must take two arguments. In this case, I think you want to `map` a function over the list and then sum all the resulting items with `sum`, instead of `foldl` (for a naive implementation of standard deviation).

You may also want to look into `genericLength` from `Data.List` which evaluates to a value that can be used as any instance of the `Num` type class (including `Float`).

Comment: I am learning higher order function so just try to implement it without sum, although it is much easier to use sum